# "No process is on the other end of the pipe" Error Occurred Randomly

Tags: sql-server

When executing procedures, the following error occurs randomly:

> Msg 233, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
>   A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

Project specifications:

- Runs locally!
- SQL Server 2017
- One normal table and one memory optimized table
- Resource Governor is enable

**UPDATE**

SQL Server Logs:

> Disallowing page allocations for database 'MyDatabase' due to insufficient memory in the resource pool 'default'. See 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=510837' for more information.

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log for related messages. If you see a stack dump or other severe errors, run `DBCC CHECKDB`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable Resource Governor
2. Detach the database
3. Reattach the database